# Save Abjad ouput pdfs

Tags: python, directory, lilypond

I'm using Abjad to create pdf's of lilypond files my python program has written.

When I use the `abjad.show()` method, I get the image that I want, but I can't figure out how to save it as a pdf somewhere my program can use.

The documentation mentions something about changing the `abjad_output_directory` in the `config.py` file, but there's no other mention of the `config.py` file.  I can't figure out where the pdf's are being saved to on my Mac.

Is there an easy way to simply save the generated pdf as a file in the same directory as the program I'm in?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`abjad.system.AbjadConfiguration`](http://abjad.mbrsi.org/api/abjad/system/AbjadConfiguration.html) might be helpful:

- It mentions where the `abjad.cfg` file is, in which you can hopefully define an output directory, and
- It has a method for finding the abjad output directory: [`abjad_output_directory`](http://abjad.mbrsi.org/api/abjad/system/AbjadConfiguration.html#abjad.system.AbjadConfiguration.AbjadConfiguration.abjad_output_directory)

I have not been able to test this myself, but hopefully it is enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the following keywords in show():

```
abjad.show(notes, output_directory=r"C:\path\to\somewhere", should_open=False)
```

Answering in case anyone else searches this question as it was hard to figure out.